# Ways to ask "save the date"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Does it sound better if I say:

> ... hope you have marked your calendars

instead of :

> ... hope you have blocked the date

for a certain event in the future for which they have already been notified ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "save this day" instead of "save the date"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70038/use-of-save-this-day-instead-of-save-the-date)

Comment: The first one sounds better.

Comment: "I hope you've marked your calendars" sounds perfectly fine.  The expression "save the date" (not "save the day," which means something else) came about exactly because there was no quick and easy way to tell others to keep a certain date available for a planned event.

Comment: In British English we're definitely more likely to just say "hope you've put it in your calendars".

Comment: @Araucaria Wouldn't we say *hope you've noted it in your diary*? Isn't it Americans who keep *calendars* rather than *diaries*?

Comment: @WS2 Quite right! Haven't had any coffee yet! I heartily second you: *Noted it in your diaries* is the one. Maybe an answer before it gets closed? You have a guaranteed upvote! (Might want to mention the British English bit).

Comment: 'I'd rarely use anything other than '... kept ____ free'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But if you ask someone to *keep 3rd June free in their diary*, are you not making the imperious assumption that they will attend, or want to attend whatever it is you are asking them? Wouldn't it be more easy-going to ask then to *note it in their diary*?

Comment: @WS2 Are you saying that there is a significant difference between 'I hope you have noted it in your diary' and 'I hope you have kept that date free'? There isn't in my experience.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They may be used in quite different circumstances. e.g. I have *noted it in my diary* that I have to make a modest income-tax payment by the end of the month - but it isn't necessary to *keep the day free* for any reason. It is perfectly alright to ask people to *keep the day free* if it accords with the normal rules of politeness, e.g.if you happen to have invited them for breakfast, lunch and afternoon tea. But not if you are expecting similar treatment from them!

Comment: @WS2 You are missing the 'I hope you' part.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  My earlier comment contained all that. But *please would you* also serves.

Comment: '... if you ask someone to keep 3rd June free in their diary' misses the  'I hope you' part. I included the ellipsis. _You_ are the one initiating the '@EdwinAshworth **But**'.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely wouldn't ask anyone to *block* their calendars. *Blocking* should be more associated with pipes and toilets than about people's arrangements, in my view.

Besides I think it sounds officious to ask people to *block* something - it sort of assumes that you are obligating them to participate in whatever it is that is happening. Asking them to *note* something makes no such imperious assumption.

In Britain we would normally ask people to *note it in their diary* or *make a note in their diary*.

I don't think Americans keep *diaries* but *calendars*. To us, a *calendar* is something you hang on the wall. A *diary* can either be in old-tech notebook form, or something you keep on your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

"I hope your calendars are blocked" is an alternative depending on the audience you are referring to.

Assuming - 
event is formal
audience is higher management

"I hope you have marked your calendar for  event. If not, please block your calendar as your presence is important"

Assuming - 
event is informal, team activity, et al.
audience is peers
"Please block your calendar for this event. Ignore this reminder, if already done"

Hope this helps.

NOTE: in the above suggestions, 'blocked' can be replaced with 'marked' :)

Comment: I don't like the use of *block* at all. Not only does it sound exceedingly officious, but *blocked* has more to do with *pipes and sewers* than it does with people's personal arrangements, in my view. *Please note it in your diary* sounds far more genteel.